# Colors going to seemingly random geom_points in ggplot2 (in R)

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a forest plot in ggplot2. Some of the categories displayed on the Y axis are grouped (i.e. multiple levels of the same factor), and so I'd like to color-code the points. But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how R is interpreting the color vector.

This is the code I'm using:

```
forest.df$labs<-c("Factor1 Level1", "Factor1 Level2", "Factor1 Level3", "Factor1 Level4", "Factor1 Level5", "Factor2 Level1", "Factor2 Level2", "Factor2 Level3", "Factor2 Level4", "Factor3 Level1", "Factor3 Level2", "Factor4", "Factor5", "Factor6", "Factor7", "Factor8")
colorname<-c("Pink", "Red", "Red", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Orange","Black")
ggplot(forest.df, aes(x=OR, y = rowname)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=exp2.5,xmax=exp97.5),height=0.667) +
  geom_point(size=5, colour=colorname)+
  scale_y_discrete(labels=forest.df$labs)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=1,linetype="dashed")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-0.3,30))
```

But this is the plot I'm getting: [image]

I feed it this color vector:

```
c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Black", "Green", "Purple", "Pink", "Orange")
```

But what comes out is something that looks more like: Black, Red, Green, Purple, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Yellow, Yellow, Orange, Yellow, Yellow, Yellow, Pink (reading bottom-to-top).

Through sheer trial and error, I was able to come up with a vector that gives me the colors I want, but I can't figure out why I would need to give R the color vector in this seemingly nonsensical order. By feeding it this vector:

```
colorname<-c("Pink", "Red", "Red", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Orange","Black")
```

I am able to get the following plot (which is what I wanted):

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on here and what I am doing wrong? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: without a reproductible example it's hard to say, but have you tried scale_color_manual() to set your colour?

Comment: I have- it also jumbles the order of the colors I put in. You think it has something to do with how ggplot is reading the df?

Comment: when you set the order of your factor level, you use the same order in scale_color_manual() and it should work

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused- why does the order of the factor _level_ matter? I want all of the levels in a given factor to be the same color, separate from other factors.

Comment: if the order of the factor are A, B, C and if you want red for A, blue for B..etc then in your scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green")) but without data it's hard to test

Comment: Perhaps I miscommunicated. If the order of the levels in factor 1 are A, B, and C, and the order of levels in factor 2 are D, E, and F, I want A, B, and C to be Red, and I want D, E, and F to be Blue. In other words, I want all the factors to be different colors, and all of the levels to be the same.

Comment: ok, so you should use 2 geom_point(), one for factor1 (geom_point(data=X, aes(x=x, y=factor1), colour="red")), and one for factor2 (geom_point(data=X, aes(x=x, y=factor2), colour="blue"))

Comment: Ahh, that's genius. I'll try that when I get home, thanks!